# Parse .doc & .docx for get all text using golang?

Tags: go, ms-word, docx, doc

How can I parse word documents ".doc", ".docx" to get all the text using golang?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? its the first result from google..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get some inspiration from those projects:

https://github.com/nguyenthenguyen/docx
https://github.com/opencontrol/doc-template

Basically, DOCX is a Zip file with XMLs in it.
All the texts are inside `document.xml`

What both project do is remove all XML tags, leaving only text intact. You should see if that approach suits you too.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

1. Unpack `docx` file using any Go zip package
2. Parse text from `‌word/document.xml`
3. If you have any other `docx` files inside `word/` folder, then repeat 1 and 2 steps for each of them recursively

---

### In most of cases…

As already mentioned, `docx` file is a basically `zip` archive with bunch of ‌`xml` files inside.

**In most of cases** all text from original file present in ‌‌‌`word/document.xml`. You can use standard `xml` package for Go to parse text from it. And also look at OpenXML documentation if you need info about different tag types.

**Upd.** You can use [this code](https://github.com/tymbaca/go-yadt/blob/816806f39d93a2e4d198323480dac1185e6b9048/utils/docx.go#L54-L93) btw.

### But…

But unfortunately there are some cases when **not all text is present in that file**.

For example if document have another embedded `docx` file (or any other format) it most likely present within `word` folder (beside `document.xml`) as a separate file.

If that’s the case, you need to unpack each of that `docx` and parse their own `document.xml`.

For more details you can check [`AltChunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk?view=openxml-2.8.1) OpenXML class as well as any other related info.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to use https://github.com/sajari/docconv.

example code:

```
f, err := os.Open("path.docx")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer f.Close()

var r io.Reader
r = f

tmpl, _, err := docconv.ConvertDocx(r)
if err != nil {
    return
}
```

this returns the docx as a string output.